# Merge a source branch to a target branch is both ways or only one way

Tags: tfs

When I merge a source branch 'Branch1' to a target branch 'IntegrationBranch', **then changes are only done to 'IntegrationBranch'** as a result ( i.e. one-way operation) **OR even 'Branch1' may get changed** in this merge operation (two-way operation)?

I am using TFS 2010.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only the target branch is changed in a merge.  So only IntegrationBranch in your example.

Comment: But sometimes, I do see a list of conflicts show up and I have the option to take source branch or target branch version. What is this about, since it seems this may be doing a 2-way merge?

Comment: I guess when merging is done, always behind-the-scenes, TFS looks at the files in the working folder on your system and checks if the files checked into source branch in TFS are same as working folder files. If not, then it shows a list of conflicts? So TFS always makes sure that the working folder files match the TFS checked in files for source branch before a merge is performed.

Comment: Conflicts occur when a file was changed in source and target branch after the branch/last merge was done. Usually TFS can solve it automatically, but when one line was changed in both branches differently, you need to decide what should be taken. This has nothing to do with your local workspace, but you should check that you do not have any pending changes in the target before starting the merge.

Comment: When it prompts you with a conflict, and the choices take source or take target, it is still only making changes to the target, it's simply asking you if you want the target to keep the target's version of that file, or overwrite the target file with the source file.